# Aptana how to active preview

Tags: java, php, xml, html

how to activate the live preview in Aptana?
in its daownload page says:
“Live Preview
Quickly switch between a view of your source code and the rendered HTML page in popular web browsers. ”
but how?

Answer (score 2):

To preview an html file, first open the html file and then click on the preview icon on the toolbar: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but I think you can simply click the green "run" button.
Here is a link to the documentation about "previewing": http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Previewing+a+project+in+a+web+browser

Comment: This is not the same thing with preview. Run button shows result in the console, which is not the same thing with preview.