# Aptana Studio 3 - SFTP - Preview not displaying CSS/JS. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, aptana

I have a website hosted that I am using Aptana to connect to the server via SFTP and edit the files there. When I preview the html file, it seems to store a temp version of the file on my local drive:

`file:///C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/aptanavfs/aptanavfs2715860739108955789index.html`

instead of using the live version... and this seems to cause it to not load the CSS/JS (I guess it's not making a copy of these files to the temp path).

What's going on? When I view the site live on the internet, everything is working fine.

Comment: I think you answered your own question, when the app is downloading the file for previewing, it is not making a local copy of the CSS/JS so it your HTML file makes reference to them using relative paths, it will not find them.  Have you checked the documentation of Aptana to see how to use the preview feature?  Maybe there is a configuration step you need to complete for all the 'related' files to come along when previewing and HTML?

Comment: I understand this, however, i can not find documentation anywhere on how to fix this issue thus I have asked a community :)

Comment: How about simply obtaining the related files from the live site over to your local (temp) folder?  SFTP is just a tool to up/download files to/from the server.  If you need to see the HTML fully rendered (which I understand is your goal), you need to have all the related files. Whether Aptana helps you achieve this or it is getting in the way, I am not sure...

Comment: Also, you may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404806/where-is-the-preview-tab-on-aptana-studio-3 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727704/aptana-how-to-active-preview   - maybe they can help you

Comment: The preview does the same thing as when I chose to Run. It copies ONLY the html file to a temp folder and displays ONLY the HTML in the preview/run. I am trying to have it so it will bring along the properly linked Javascript and CSS files so the page displays correctly. This seemingly should be done automatically, however, it isn't. This is where my frustration is. I can open up my browser and view my live site via www and see it update live as I save my work in Aptana. I just feel as if the Run/Preview feature should work properly.

Comment: I am suspecting you may need to synchronize the remote files with the ones found on your local machine.  Are the files on your PC in-sync with the ones on the server? try this if they are not: http://www.danielrosca.ro/blog/en/aptana-studio-and-ftp-server/ -> check the Sync options (step 7) to ensure you copy the missing files from your server to your computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files from your remote server might not be synchronized with the files on your computer.

Check your Synchronization options to ensure you tell Aptana to 'sync from your remote site to your machine' - if you do not have all the files from the server on your computer, you need to do this at least once before you start working on your changes.

After this, you will want to decide how to keep the changes made on your computer in sync with the server (either manually upload them yourself, or tell Aptana to automatically synchronize them)

Check this page for a brief tutorial on how to set up the sync options (step 7): 
http://www.danielrosca.ro/blog/en/aptana-studio-and-ftp-server/

Comment: I do not have the Sync Options. I am in the REMOTE tab accessing my files from my web server. When I rightlick>properties of my remote connection it shows the same window as step 4-6, however there is no sync options. I do not have a local project made for this.

Comment: If you are editing the file on the server directly (which is in itself a bad practice) - then you can simply look at the server version directly on your browser.  My understanding is that you do not want that, you want to preview your changes. For this, standard practice is to create a local project, edit your files there, preview them and when satisfied with your changes, you can upload them to the remote server.

Comment: That would be the issue then. Thank you for clarifying. I am doing live updates on the server files. I will create a local project and sync the files this way. Thanks for all the assistance and I will accept this answer as correct.

Comment: glad to be of help... Just as a side-note: it is poor practice to edit the live files directly because if you make a mistake, everyone will see it right away.  Not to mention that you could accidentally delete something and not be able to recover it... On top of that, it limits you to work only when you have a connection to the server (but sometimes you can make the changes on your local copy and only upload them when you get a connection)